# Template assignment operator in template class copying inner class issue

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, assignment-operator

I have a template class containing an inner class. On the operator=() overload I want to copy an instance of the inner class but get an error:

```
no known conversion from 'const foo<double>::bar' to 'const foo<int>::bar'
```

The code looks like (You can find an example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a02ff938ace004b)):

```
template<typename T>
class foo {
public:
    template<typename>
    friend class foo;

    class bar {
        std::string inner_str;
    public:
        bar const& operator=(bar const& r) {
            inner_str = r.inner_str;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    template<typename F>
    foo const& operator=(foo<F> const& r) {
        value = static_cast<T>(r.value);
        str_container = r.str_container;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    bar str_container;
    T value;
};
```

Moving `bar` outside `foo` works fine, but the inner class should be part of `foo`.

**How to solve this issue?** I thought about making `bar` friend like foo is friend to all specializations of foo. But I don't know how to introduce them.

<sub>Sidenote: Please feel free to change the title since I don't really know how to title this specific problem.</sub>

Comment: Should `foo<A>::bar` be an unrelated type to `foo<B>::bar`? If not, you could make a base-class which has `bar` as an inner type and derive your `foo<T>` instances from that.

Comment: Nice idea, but that would also require a class outside foo. Is there some other possibility?

Comment: Why don't you want a class outside `foo`?

Comment: So we're clear, I'm talking about something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98902dcd11edfbc6).

Comment: foo is kind a interface shared between different components. Simply said, it would be nice if the interface is containing everything inside, instead of having them separated. If it is not possible it is fine if bar is outside, but I thought in c++ it should be possible and I am just missing something. Also it would be nice to know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you should put `bar` outside of `foo` and just put them in some `interface` namespace.

Comment: There is already an interface namespace containing some interfaces :) . Hmmm I thought i was just missing the fancy c++ magic to solve this issue, but seems there is no way...

Comment: Then you could make this a nested namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo<double>::bar` is a completely unrelated type to `const foo<int>::bar`, so you cannot convert between them implicitly.

Since `bar` appears to not depend on a template argument, this would seem like a sensible solution:

> Moving bar outside foo works fine

Problem solved :)

> but the inner class should be part of `foo`.

Considering how you use it, I would argue that no, it should not be part of `foo`.

Alternatively, you could make the assignment operator of `bar` a template just like you did with the assignment operator of `foo`:

```
template<typename B>
bar const& operator=(const B& r) {
    inner_str = r.inner_str;
    return *this;
}
template<typename U>
friend class foo<U>::bar; // this bar must be friends with other bars
```

If the definition of `bar` does depend on the template argument of `foo`, then you could use this approach. Otherwise, it wouldn't make much sense to define an identical, but separate inner class inside every `foo`.

Comment: I will give the alternative approach a try and let you know.

Comment: @user1810087 I updated the alternative approach with one that works.

Comment: Add to that:  if bar is inside foo just to keep organized (not pollute the global namespace with bar that's only used by foo) use a non-template base class or a namespace to hold both foo and bar and then expose foo outside of that internal namespace.

Comment: Interestingly clang is generating a warning (`warning: dependent nested name specifier 'foo<U>::' for friend class declaration is not supported; turning off access control for 'bar' [-Wunsupported-friend] friend class foo<U>::bar;`) while gcc and visual studio don't. But apart from that it works fine. Thank you.